# How can i generate json response from rabl gem and money gem with the database table i have?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, currency, rabl

This is the json i want to build from rabl gem

```
[
"M-0": {"revenue":"value", "fee":"value", "created":"count", "paid":"count", "partially_paid":"count"},
"M-1": {"revenue":"value", "fee":"value", "created":"count", "paid":"count", "partially_paid":"count"},
"M-2": {"revenue":"value", "fee":"value", "created":"count", "paid":"count", "partially_paid":"count"},
"M-3": ["revenue":"value", "fee":"value", "created":"count", "paid":"count", "partially_paid":"count"],
"M-4": {"revenue":"value", "fee":"value", "created":"count", "paid":"count", "partially_paid":"count"},
"M-5": {"revenue":"value", "fee":"value", "created":"count", "paid":"count", "partially_paid":"count"}
 ]
```

This is my database table

```
create_table "merchant_monthly_stats", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "created_count",        default: 0
    t.integer  "ready_count",          default: 0
    t.integer  "paid_count",           default: 0
    t.integer  "partially_paid_count", default: 0
    t.integer  "cancelled_count",      default: 0
    t.integer  "failed_count",         default: 0
    t.integer  "processed_count",      default: 0
    t.integer  "expired_count",        default: 0
    t.integer  "merchant_id",                          null: false
    t.integer  "year",                                 null: false
    t.integer  "month",                                null: false
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "overdue_count",        default: 0
    t.integer  "fee_centimes",         default: 0,     null: false
    t.string   "fee_currency",         default: "XAF", null: false
    t.integer  "revenue_centimes",     default: 0,     null: false
    t.string   "revenue_currency",     default: "XAF", null: false
  end
```

This is my controller method

```
def history
    current_month = Time.now.month
    current_year = Time.now.year
    list_of_last_six_months = [current_month]
    5.times do |i|
      list_of_last_six_months << (current_month - i )
    end 

    month_array =[]
    list_of_last_six_months.each { |month|
      record = MerchantMonthlyStat.find_by merchant_id: current_api_user.id, year: current_year, month: month
      m = { 
        :revenue => Money.new(record.revenue_centimes , record.revenue_currency).format,
        :fees => Money.new(record.fee_centimes,record.fee_currency).format, 
        :created => record.created_count , 
        :paid => record.paid_count , 
        :partially_paid => record.partially_paid_count }
      month_array.push(m)
    }
    respond_with(month_array, status: :ok, template: 'api/merchant/mobiles/history')
  end
```

**My question is how do i write the rabl template 'api/merchant/mobiles/history' to get the above json response ?**

Note : I am using rails money gem. Thats why there is Money.new etc

**Update**:

If i have following :

```
# app/app.rb
get "/posts", :provides => [:json, :xml] do
  @user = current_user
  @posts = Post.order("id DESC")
  render "posts/index"
end
```

Rabl docs have written following rabl for it(which does not make sense to me) :

```
# app/views/posts/index.rabl
collection @posts
attributes :id, :title, :subject
child(:user) { attributes :full_name }
node(:read) { |post| post.read_by?(@user) }
```

But i dont know how to apply this to get my month_array in rabl and in the format i want ? Anybody wanting to solve this ? I am stuck.

Comment: But what you provided doesn't look like JSON. What are these `M-0`, `M-1`, etc. labels?

Comment: I don't see any efforts. Your question is _write code for me_.

Comment: So what do you think who wrote rest of the things above? They are not efforts ? I just dont know lot in rails. I am learning since a week and thats the progress i could do. Thats all.

Comment: @EugZol i have corrected the json in question

Comment: @Зелёный i am asking to teach me how to do it.  And not write code. Don't write it. Tell me how its done. Whats the process ?

Comment: @samo if you do not know much in Rails, I suggest following the Rails Guides "Getting Started" chapter, or doing Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial. If you do not know much rails, it is difficult to understand how to use other gems with your app.

Comment: @samo [rabl gem](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl) has a lot of documentation, wonderful wiki pages and many examples in web. So this can be done if you try.

Comment: @samo SO is about teaching, but given a specific question. This is too broad. I would suggest asking this on a traditional forum (Google Groups? Reddit?) Rather than Q&A like SO.

Comment: @ Hunter Stevens so what do i do with current task? I need to achieve it. See if you guys dont know how to do it, please keep quite or if you want to help me, and you need more information, ask me.

Comment: All i am asking is tell me some advice on syntax of rabl for generating a json arrray with values that i have in month_array. How can it be broad ? Think up guys, i think you can do it if you know rabl json api syntax ,given an array of information and a template to write it. Though i can not score a goal because i have never used rabl json api.

Comment: I think i got lot of down votes for posting a good question that can be useful to others who have data but dont know rabl syntax. This is so rude.

Comment: Thanks to those who actually see the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `render :json`

```
render json: month_array
```

No need to mess with templating, you already have built your array in controller.

**Update from comments**: Make month_array instance vairable – change my_array to @my_array. And then in your rabl template just write collection @my_array, object_root: false

Comment: Actually i proposed this to my senior already since i can easily do it. But he said we are using rabl, and i need to learn it. Otherwise i would have marked you as answer. :(

Comment: Well, you can make month_array instance vairable – change `my_array` to `@my_array`. And then in your rabl template just write `collection @my_array, object_root: false`

Comment: You are welcome. If your senior will ask you to refactor code to move more things from your controller to Rabl, feel free to ask another question, we'll figure something out :) Also, consider upvoting my answer if you like it.

Comment: But i already marked it as an answer. Since that was most helpful. Could you please update your answer ?

Comment: Thanks Eugzol. http://teohm.com/blog/2011/05/31/using-rabl-in-rails-json-web-api/ this also helped me to learn rabl syntax, in case someone wants to understand better